# Define then Undefine Preprocessor Variables within Macro

Tags: c++, macros

I would like to create a macro like the following, which would be used to create two functions: one with debugging enabled and one without debugging enabled.

```
#define MakeDebuggerFunction(funName, funContents)\
    void funName() funContents\
    #define DEBUGGING\
    void funName ## _debugging() funContents\
    #undef DEBUGGING
```

And the way this would be used would be like the following

```
MakeDebuggerFunction(DoWork,
    {
        std::cout << "Doing Work" << std::endl;
        #ifdef DEBUGGING
            std::cout << "Printing Verbose" << std::endl;
        #endif
    }
)
```

This would result in two functions: DoWork and DoWork_debugging. Where both functions would have the same exact "guts" of the code for that function, but the debugging function would also have some verbose printing added.

The reason I want both functions created is because my GUI application has a "developer mode" which I can use when I'm out of the office and onsite with customers, where I don't have the luxury of a true debugging environment.

Many of these functions are also very processing intensity so I want to avoid doing something like adding a permanent `if(DeveloperMode) {}` statement wrapping my verbose code.

Any help/suggestions I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't possible using the standard C preprocessor

Comment: "I want to avoid doing something like adding a permanent `if(DeveloperMode) {}` statement wrapping my verbose code." If the `DeveloperMode` is set to a constant value (so that every place that uses it knows its compile-time value), any reasonable optimizing compiler should eliminate the branch

Comment: it's not set at compile time. I open a dialog and enter a password which would make `DeveloperMode==true` (at runtime)

Comment: Not sure what your target OS platform is however could you have two versions of a shared library (or DLL) and just swap out the component to either have your debug mode or not? Are you recompiling the application at the customer site in order to run it? This approach is compile time binding and not run time binding.

Comment: You could make 3 functions: 1 that has an extra `bool debugging` parameter, and 2 that forward on to it. E.g. `DoWork_impl(..., bool debugging)`, `DoWork(...) { return DoWork_impl(..., false); }`, `DoWork_debugging(...) { return DoWork_impl(..., true); }`. Again, the optimizing compiler should handle any branches inside `DoWork_impl`, but only if the body of the `impl` function is known (e.g. in the header, or with Link Time Optimizations). You *can* generate these 3 functions via a macro if you wanted

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what @Justin was suggesting

I would make my wrapper function like this:

```
void DoWork_Wrapper()
{
    if (DeveloperMode)
        DoWork(..., true);
    else
        DoWork(...., false);
}
```

and the worker function would be:

```
void DoWork(..., bool DeveloperMode)
{
    /// do some stuff
    if (DeveloperMode)
        /// print verbose
}
```

So when I make the call to `DoWork(..., false)` the compiler has already optimized out the if-statements?

Comment: It sounds like to me that you are confusing functionality that is bound at compile time with functionality that is bound at run time.

Comment: Well, this could possibly work, if the compiler decides to inline `DoWork`, or if link time optimization magic happens.  (I don't know how smart LTO typically is.)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way. You can make your debug function inline and it will be completely transparent. Of course you will have to work around more complex debug messages and adjust your debug function appropriately. It would be much better than making duplicates of your functions.

```
void debug(string s) {
  if (DeveloperMode) {
    std::cout << s << "\n";
  }
}


 std::cout << "Doing Work" << std::endl;
 debug("Printing Verbose");
```

Or you can use one of the looging libraries out there. E.g. Log4c.

Comment: some of my functions are extremely processing intensive so I want to avoid doing a runtime check of `if(DeveloperMode)` inside of them...

Comment: @Stanton You could combine this with Richard Chambers' suggestion. Most logging libraries out there have something like `LOG_DEBUG("msg")`, which is a macro so that you can `#define` something (usually you'd do so in your build system) that makes those log messages go away. You could then compile 2 DLLs that either has or doesn't have the logging information.

Comment: Then you would be left with #ifdefs around your debug outputs. And you will need to build two versions of application. One with debug enabled and second with debug disabled. And if your checks at runtime will slow you down so significantly, I somehow doubt that you will be able to get any debugging done this way. Since your application will come to halt the moment you enable debug mode. And you will have ton of output. You really need proper logging management.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but if you can compile one version with debugging enabled and one without you can just add a DEBUGGING compile flag to the debugging one and do the following

```
#ifdef DEBUGGING
#define debugPrint(verboseMessage)            \
    std::cout << verboseMessage << std::endl;
#else
#define debugPrint(verboseMessage)
#endif
```

This will make it so you can always call this macro and if debugging is on it will actually print your message, otherwise nothing will happen.

HTH!